# Reading Comprehension Question couldn't find any satisfying explanation online

Tags: reading, gre

> Exotic insect pests can produce both short-and long-term effects on forest ecosystems. Shortterm effects include the disturbances directly associated with the action of the pest, which may cause the defoliation, loss of vigor, or death of trees. Long-term effects are primarily mediated by changes in tree species composition and the consequent alterations of forest structure, productivity, and nutrient uptake. Exotic pests are more efficient than most abiotic disturbances (e.g., fire or wind) at producing long-term changes in species composition. Pests often target specific tree species and, if they become established, they usually remain as permanent components of the ecosystem. Shifts in forest species composition ramify through the ecosystem in many ways because tree species have different, often unique properties.

> The author of the passage mentions the “unique properties” of tree species primarily in order to help explain
>
> A. why pests tend to target specific tree species
>
> B. why pests can have long-term effects on entire ecosystems
>
> C. how pests contribute to shifts in forest species composition
>
> D. how pests are able to become established in an ecosystem
>
> E. how some tree species are able to withstand the effects of pests

Answer is C. However my understanding of the last key sentence is that in writing "ramify through the ecosystem", the author is emphasizing the effects pests have are on the entire system (through changing forest species composition). This led me to answer B instead.

Comment: Are you sure the answer isn't B?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately

Comment: Forgive me, but the expectation of finding *any satisfying explanation online* is similar to expecting it here. Just saying.

Comment: Why are you so sure that the answer key you have is correct?

Comment: Because a number of sources online all list C as the answer and I haven't had any reason to question all the other answers these sources have provided so far.

Comment: That's not a reading comprehension test, it's a writing incomprehension test.

Comment: The sources online may be unreliable ... certainly, they all copy each other, so it may be the first source to post it got it wrong, and everybody else copied them.

Comment: @PeterShor I take it that you reckon B is the answer?

Comment: Yes, I think B is the answer.

Comment: The sentence that mentions "different, often unique properties" specifically says that this is the reason for "shifts in forest species". Isn't that why the answer is C?

Comment: B refers to the theme of the entire paragraph, not that sentence. @PeterShor

Answer (score 0):

The answer is C because the unique properties of certain tree species are only mentioned in the last sentence:

> Shifts in forest species composition ramify through the ecosystem in many ways because tree species have different, often unique properties.

That sentence says that the existence of unique properties is the reason for shifts in corest species composition.

The other choices refer to other points made in the paragraph, but they're not specifically related to this aspect.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It says that shifts in forest species composition produce many changes in the entire ecosystem, but it doesn't say what causes the shifts in forest species composition.

Comment: What does "because" mean then?

Comment: Answer C says "Because of pests, the composition of forest species shifts." The last sentence says "Because trees have different properties, ...*  So to get from the last sentence to C, you need to link pests with trees having different properties. But that's wrong—trees don't have different properties because of pests, and nothing in the passage implies they do.

Comment: I see what you're saying. But it's still the case that the last sentence is the only one that mentions "shifts", and it also mentioned "unique properties". Answer B is about long-term effects, which are discussed in other parts of the paragraph and are not specifically linked to "unique properties".